# Bitbucket Server Installation Error

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm attempting to install Bitbucket server on my linux server. I'm following the steps [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/getting-started-776640896.html). I'm stuck at step 3. I've installed Bitbucket server, and now when trying to "Setup Bitbucket Server" I'm not able to access it from my browser.

I've done the following:

1. Using SSH I've went to the directory containing `/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/`
2. I run the command `bin/start-bitbucket.sh`.

it gives the following message:

```
Starting Atlassian Bitbucket as current user

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  JAVA_HOME "/usr/local/jdk" does not point to a valid Java home directory.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitbucket is being run with a umask that contains potentially unsafe settings.
The following issues were found with the mask "u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx" (0002):
 - access is allowed to 'others'. It is recommended that 'others' be denied
   all access for security reasons.
 - write access is allowed to 'group'. It is recommend that 'group' be
   denied write access. Read access to a restricted group is recommended
   to allow access to the logs.

The recommended umask for Bitbucket is "u=,g=w,o=rwx" (0027) and can be
configured in setenv.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using BITBUCKET_HOME:      /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/bin/bitbucket-bootstrap.jar:/home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/wbbstaging/atlassian/bitbucket/4.4.1/work/catalina.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Tomcat started.

Success! You can now use Bitbucket at the following address:

http://localhost:7990/

If you cannot access Bitbucket at the above location within 3 minutes, or encounter any other issues starting or stopping Atlassian Bitbucket, please see the troubleshooting guide at:
```

I try to access `http://myserveraddress:7990`, but i receive `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message. Is it because of the message `JAVA_HOME "/usr/local/jdk" does not point to a valid Java home directory`?

My server is running:
`CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511`

And I'm attempting to install
`Bitbucket Server 4.4.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have java installed by running              java --version
2. If it's not installed, start there. If it is installed, verify where by running find /-name java
3. Open /root/.bash_profile through your text editor. (I prefer to use vi editor)
   And paste the given below two lines(noting that my below version may be different from what you see)

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21
   export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin:$PATH
4. Now enable the Java variable without system restart (On system restart it bydefault set the java variable)

   source /root/.bash_profile
5. Now check the Java version,JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.It should show you correct information as you have set.

   java --version

   echo $JAVA_HOME

   echo $PATH

Below is my system’s root bash_profile file

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /root/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup      programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin:$PATH
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: My Java home location is:

`/usr/lib/jvm/`

and my path variable is set to:

`/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/`

in my root users bash profile. How can I make proper changes for Bitbucket now?

Comment: Do you have tomcat installed?

Comment: I'll ask my host. If so would I use that to make Bitbucker Server point to the right directory? it seems its pointing at /usr/local/jvm/ instead of /usr/lib/jvm

Comment: I'm not convinced that will change the pointer but it will help rule out a subset of problems. So you are using a hosted instance? If so, can you open a ticket with them? I suspect that they may have some type of policy changing the pointer for one reason or another

Comment: I have a dedicated server. I'm attempting to install Bitbucket Server on it. They said they set the path variable to `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/` and that my java home is located here: `/usr/lib/jvm/` should i ask about Tomcat?

Comment: I would. I would also ask if they are emptying any type of policies

Comment: hi, I solved the JAVA issue with your help. Now I no longer get the java issue, but when trying to access the server localhost with the port i get:

`SSL connection error`. Am I on the right path?

Comment: This is the base URL for this installation of Bitbucket Server. All links which are not from a web request (for example in Bitbucket Server email notifications), will be prefixed by this URL. If you are experiencing trouble with setting an https base URL, please ensure you have configured Tomcat with SSL correctly.
To specify Bitbucket Server's base URL:
In the Bitbucket Server administration area, click Server settings (under 'Settings').
In the Base URL field, type the URL address of your Bitbucket Server instance (for example, "https://bitbucket.mycompany.com").
Click Save.

Comment: I got it! It works now! Now would you recommend PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: This is awesome news and I am super happy!!! My personal preference would be for MySQL for simple speed

Comment: Thank you kindly for that but I did nothing but collaborate with you. You did the testing, the work and ultimately you are due all the credit. I am super happy you trusted you could fix it and now you have a new confidence to tackle more. Good luck to you :-)

Comment: Thanks! After this I'm installing JIRA and Confluence.

Comment: And then you can install script runner for writing groovy and testing automation against your new jira and confluence. Automation is everything ;-)

Comment: I personally have not used the product but from a pricing perspective (Atlassian family) I have heard from others that it is compelling enough to have everything under one umbrella per se